# Why do I get an undefined method error when trying to loop through a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code:

```
  in_msg.updateComments.map{|c| c.values}.each do |comment|
    ...
  end
```

where `in_msg.updateComments` is a hash. For some reason the first line if this snippet returns an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `values' for #<Array:0x1382da058>
```

I am not sure why this happens. Any idea why it might happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `map` method returns an `Enumerator`, which is going to loop over each key value pair in your hash, but it yields an array, not a hash, so `c` will look like `[key, value]` instead of `{key => value}`.

`Array` doesn't implement `values`, which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: thank you for the explaination. That makes it much more clear :)

Comment: Whoa, I think that's the most rep I've gotten off one question!

Comment: `map` only returns an `Enumerator` when it is called without a block. Here, it is called *with* a block.

Answer (score 1):

This could work, provided `updateComments` only contains hashes and arrays:

```
in_msg.updateComments.map do |c|
  if c.respond_to?(:values)
    c.values
  else
    c
  end
end.each do |comment|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what `Hash#map` yields is not hash, but a array `[key,value]`.

```
irb> {a:1,b:2}.map {|arg| p arg}
[:a, 1]
[:b, 2]
=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

=============

if you want to iterate over values of a hash, `a_hash.values.each` or `a_hash.each` will be fine.